# How to insert values of one tensor into another?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to insert tensor y into the tensors x final dimension (y_dim). The final tensor should be of size (100, 16, 16, 1) where the values of y are placed in each of 100 x 0dimension

```
import torch

y_dim = 1
x = torch.randn(100, 16, 16, y_dim)
#OR x = torch.randn(100, 16, 16)
y = torch.randn(100)

Xy = torch.cat((x, y), dim=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing something in your understanding of tensors and dimensions. The easiest thing is to consider your tensor `x` as a batch containing `100` maps of width and height `16`, *i.e.* `100` `16x16`-maps. So you are manipulating a tensor containing `100*16*16` elements. Your `y`, on the other hand, contains `100` scalar values, it has `100` elements.

I'm turning the question back to you:

> How would you concatenate `100` `16x16`-maps with `100` scalar values?

---

The above question has no answer. There are certain things that can be done though, assumptions that can be made on `y` in order to perform a concatenation:

- If you had a tensor `y` containing `16x16` maps as well, then yes this operation would be achievable:

  ```
  >>> x = torch.rand(100, 16, 16)
  >>> y = torch.rand(100, 16, 16)

  >>> torch.cat((x, y)).shape
  torch.Size([200, 16, 16])
  ```
- If you consider the `y` in your question, you could expand the `100` scalar values to `16x16` maps. And, then concatenate with `x`:

  ```
  >>> x = torch.rand(100, 16, 16)
  >>> y = torch.rand(100)

  >>> y_r = y[:,  None, None].repeat(1, 16, 16)
  >>> torch.cat((x, y_r))
  torch.Size([200, 16, 16])
  ```

Comment: I see, what I am trying to do is fit 100 maps 16 width and 16 height with 100x1 labels from y

Comment: Yes, I understood that was your question. However this simply can't be done, do you understand why? I can provide more explanation if needed.

Comment: I think i understand? Is it because adding another dimension would turn each WidthHeight sample into WidthHeightDepth? Meaning the label would be repeated 16x16 times?

Comment: Indeed that would correspond to my 2nd bullet point, where `y` values are repeated 16x16 times.